# See image level changes made in Photoshop in real time in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, svg

How do I open an image in both Adobe Illustrator and Photoshop (interlinked) so that after I place an SVG filter on the image in Illustrator and I change the levels of the image in photoshop, the level changes will happen in real time to the image also in Illustrator, consequently changing the SVG filter results also in real time?

I need to adjust the levels while having the SVG filter on, to be able to produce the optimal filter output.

Here is my filter:

```
<svg class="yellow_black_blue" width="320" height="280" viewBox="0 0 320 280" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<defs class="levels_ui--svgDefs"><filter id="yellow_black_blue"><feColorMatrix type="matrix" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" values="0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0"></feColorMatrix><feComponentTransfer color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"><feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0.4117647058823529 0.0392156862745098 0.9647058823529412"></feFuncR><feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0.7490196078431373 0.054901960784313725 0.8901960784313725"></feFuncG><feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0.6039215686274509 0.058823529411764705 0.5803921568627451"></feFuncB></feComponentTransfer></filter></defs>
</svg>
```

Place, place linked and place embedded won't work for me.
What I tried is to drag the image after the filter is on in Illustrator, into Photoshop, it seems that it will place the image, and the changes are shown in real time, but level changes in my black and white image should result color distribution changes according to my SVG filter, but I can only see level changes sent back to Illustrator, the distribution of colors won't change.
You can try this filter on on any of your high contrast black and white images to reproduce the issue.
I know what I want is possible because I did it a few years ago.
I just don't remember how.
When I changed the levels in Photoshop, the distribution of my filter colors (multitone filter) on the image in Illustrator with the filter on, changed.
Now only the levels change in Illustrator :((

This works with InkScape / Gimp.
I open the image in InkScape, apply the SVG filter, then I open the image in Gimp as "open as link". I change the levels in Gimp and when I save it, the changes are visible in InkScape instantly. However I cannot undo after I saved it. :(

This should somehow work between Illustrator / Photoshop or I should be able to import and use an SVG filter in photoshop, without Illustrator. How do I do that?

And it shouldn't be necessary to save to see the changes, because I cannot undo after saving.

The changes should be live, instead.

How do I do that?

Comment: You can not(natively). But you can make it update once illustrator gets focus (alt tabbing in for example), by changing illustrator preferences. So i suppose you could use extendscript to set update focus but you would forego using photoshops gui.

Comment: Anyway why dont you do levels in a svg filter?

Comment: Get the [Phantasm plugin for Illustrator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2IWj.png) from AstuteGraphics and just adjust levels within Illustrator. (I'm not affiliated with Astute Graphics.)

Comment: Thanks @Scott checking that out.

Comment: @joojaa how do I do levels in svg filters to see changes real time?

Comment: But the best would be to create the svg filter (or some fx clone equivalent) as a layer in Photoshop and use the native curves in Photoshop to see the changes in real time. How do I import an SVG filter into Photoshop or convert it into a Photoshop effect file?

Comment: @Scott thanks I tried the Phantasm plugin, but changing the curves will not change the color distribution of my filter, because the filter is not a separate layer in Illustrator. It doesn't change the curves of the image but the curves of the image + the filter.. after the curves has changed, even if I reapply the filter, the change is made to the image + the filter.

Comment: The only thing that works for me currently (not quite real time change as I would like it): open the photo with the filter on in inkscape: https://i.imgur.com/dDLLtHn.png (i know screenshot is AI but its the same) then right click, edit external, file opens in gimp, i edit the curves, overwrite original image, result: https://i.imgur.com/CLqEHsx.png . this is correct but not live change and its not photoshop or AI. then I open the image in AI with the filter on: https://i.imgur.com/dDLLtHn.png and then I change the curves with phantasm and the result is wrong:https://i.imgur.com/rBNYWbA.png

Comment: Well the **same** thing can be done with AI/PS.. In AI *link* raster image.. add SVG filter... Highlight raster image in AI **Links Panel** ... choose `Edit Original` from Panel menu.. Image opens in PS.. do whatever... save.. return to AI.. asked if you want to update the linked image... hit yes.. raster image updates, SVG filter still in place. This doesn't really fix the "need to overwrite the raster image" though. To be honest, I don't thinks there's a solution to that particular aspect. (I suggested Phantasm without realizing the *actual* goal was to change what the filter alters.)

Comment: @scott, great, the PS/AI trick works. The only issue is that the changes cannot be seen real time. It seems that for the filter to recompute the results, the image need to be saved first, and the filter reapplied (AI reapplies it automatically after image changed I guess?)? Is it svglayers.com the PS plugin that I need to see changes real time? Why won't Phantasm render the correct filter change after adjusting the curves like the AI/PS trick does? Yes, the goal is to redistribute the filter colors on the multitone image by changing the curves of the underlying black and white image.